# How can I keep video background from refreshing when loading another page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, background

I have a fullscreen video background in my index.php. I would like it to NOT reload - keep playing- when I navigate through other pages. How can I achieve that in a simple manner?

Comment: It can only be possible if you load the content using ajax in a part of the page. Hitting a link will always open a new page

Comment: Make the header section static and primary content area to be loaded via ajax. Everytime you click on link you have to load new html content for the page via ajax. No other option is there for this